# Simple to advanced SQL queries examples to practice MySQL query performance optimization

Tags: sql, mysql

Looking for **websites/books** SQL  queries from simple to advance (queries optimization and performanance etc.. ) questions and examples to  exam for MySQL Job.

Thanks

Comment: You actually could do a lot worse than browse the MySQL questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple material coverage the online MySQL docs or the `MySQL 5 Certification Study Guide` book are pretty good. Can practice on a sample database like [Employee](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employee.html) (4 million records in total) from MySQL.

For advanced subjects (performance optimization) I suggest `High Performance MySQL` book. Chapter 4 of this book deals with Query Performance Optimization, with examples using [Sakila database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila.html) from MySQL as well.